# React Native :react-native-maps:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I installed `react-native-maps` which works great on IOS but when I run `react-native run-android` I get the following error:

```
> Task :react-native-maps:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapModule.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIBlock;
                                   ^
  symbol:   class UIBlock
  location: package com.facebook.react.uimanager
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/RegionChangeEvent.java:15: error: no suitable constructor found for Event(int)
    super(id);
    ^
    constructor Event.Event() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Event.Event(int,long) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapModule.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
    uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock() {
                             ^
  symbol:   class UIBlock
  location: class AirMapModule
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapModule.java:149: error: cannot find symbol
    uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock()
                             ^
  symbol:   class UIBlock
  location: class AirMapModule
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapModule.java:192: error: cannot find symbol
    uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock()
                             ^
  symbol:   class UIBlock
  location: class AirMapModule
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapModule.java:229: error: cannot find symbol
    uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock()
                             ^
  symbol:   class UIBlock
  location: class AirMapModule
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapModule.java:262: error: cannot find symbol
    uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock()
                             ^
  symbol:   class UIBlock
  location: class AirMapModule
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/ViewAttacherGroup.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    this.setOverflow("hidden"); // Change to ViewProps.HIDDEN until RN 0.57 is base
        ^
  symbol: method setOverflow(String)
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapView.java:129: error: getCurrentActivity() is not public in ReactContext; cannot be accessed from outside package
    if (!contextHasBug(appContext.getCurrentActivity())) {
                                 ^
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapView.java:130: error: getCurrentActivity() is not public in ReactContext; cannot be accessed from outside package
      superContext = appContext.getCurrentActivity();
                               ^
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapView.java:133: error: cannot find symbol
      if (!contextHasBug(reactContext.getCurrentActivity())) {
                                     ^
  symbol:   method getCurrentActivity()
  location: variable reactContext of type ThemedReactContext
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapView.java:134: error: cannot find symbol
        superContext = reactContext.getCurrentActivity();
                                   ^
  symbol:   method getCurrentActivity()
  location: variable reactContext of type ThemedReactContext
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapMarkerManager.java:127: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
/Users/juliencorbin/theTKMapp/node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/maps/AirMapMarkerManager.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
    super.setZIndex(view, zIndex);
         ^
  symbol: method setZIndex(AirMapMarker,float)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
14 errors
```

I have those packages:

```
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.58.4",
"react-native-maps": "^0.23.0"
```

here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            // url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

and my `app/build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.thetkmapp"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}" //added this line after this react-native-maps bug but didn't solve the problem
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

I really have no idea what I could do to solve this issue. Any idea ??

Comment: why do I get -1 ? if you need further information to help me, please tell me what I can add to my explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try splitting out your maven repos:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

See here for some more details: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2090

Comment: Hi @ageoff thank you for your help, I tried this but then got the following error: `Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-maps:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0.`

Maybe it isn't related ? not sure.

Comment: Try adding this to your other build.gradle within your app directory: `implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"`

Comment: just tried it; got this error when the `gradle.build` reaches this line. `> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.`

Comment: Can you include your build.gradle within you app directory to the question?

Comment: just edited my post to add my app's `build.gradle` :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing `node_modules` and re-installing depedencies often solve this issue.

```
rm -fr node_modules
yarn
```